# Normrnd Function generating same random numbers

Tags: matlab

Is it possible that a normrnd function of matlab generates same set of random numbers on two different machines (when no seed has been set)?

Answer (score 1):

It may be if both generators are seeded the same way on both machine (ex. launched at same time, and seeded with current time). Actually, as mentionned in comment, seeding in Matlab is not with current time, so is the same at launch if not seeded.

- If you WISH to reproduce the same series of random numbers, you may take a look at this example: you can save the current seed and reuse it later.

> Save the current generator settings in s:

```
> s = rng; Call rand to generate a vector of random values:

> x = rand(1,5)

> x =

    0.8147    0.9058    0.1270    0.9134    0.6324
```

> Restore the original generator settings by calling rng. Generate a new set of
>   random values and verify that x and y are equal:

```
> rng(s); y = rand(1,5)

> y =

      0.8147    0.9058    0.1270    0.9134    0.6324
```

- Matlab gives you possibility to choose also a generator. Choosing a
  Pseudo Random Number Generator as Mersenne Twister, and seeding it
  with same seed at each run, you will get same series.
- If you wish to have a different series of randm numbers at each run,
  you can use `rng('shuffle')`, then seeding your generator with clock
  time at start.

Comment: Matlab does not default seeding based on clock, if memory serves.  Therefore each time you start matlab, your first random number will always be the same, unless you have seeded things in your startup.m.